# Phrases - pass through

Tags: word-usage

Hello I have a silly question. For example if you are in a bus or in the underground and you want to stop in a station but there are some people in front of the bus door how you address to them.

Excuse me can I pass through?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the UK, it is sufficient to say "Excuse me." Most people will know what you want and step aside for you. If you get a blank stare, then you should say "May I pass?", not "Can I pass?"

If you say "Can I walk the dog?", you are asking if you have the ability to walk the dog and, of course, you do. If you wish to ask for permission, you should say "May I walk the dog?" Unfortunately, most English speakers in the UK do not know their own language and will use "can" when they should really use "may".

As for "pass" and "pass through" (or "come through", for that matter), they all pretty much mean the same thing.

Your question is not silly at all.